# DES Encryption after Base64 encoding gives different result

Tags: java, encryption, arduino, des

I have a Java BMS application with Java clients running on RPi. However, I like to add Arduino units to the system as they are simpler, but ideally using the same communication protocol.

I encrypt a JSON with DES and then encode it with Base64.

```
    DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF8"));
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    byte[] cleartext = data.getBytes("UTF8");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // cipher is not thread safe
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] finalByte = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(finalByte);
```

For the following JSON this results in the bytes (as HEX):

```
json: {"result":"SUCCESS","message":"(none)", "actions":[{"action":"campAlarm","value":"false"},{"action":"warningBeep","value":"false"},{"action":"gpio_21","value":0}]}
Encrypted: 1e64fd8c074b2eda044f2ed820dab06949e5a2c5602918b13779e906c2733c1719965a456e2127fef0c910cbbbfcd137c535c9423cc14e7e757ddbe9f74ea307d7584eed404e31ff4cb069c40b2464eff5a6705666900a5706950b87df995e8252ed2dfb1070287c080a3527b3c40a2749c2982d033279b827cde81829d2a8d7568808caa6604a32ef41fe9b1a2fdbd3e79d5107938e6b179100c7f542cfe8cb433750ea38954bd9
Base64 encoded: HmT9jAdLLtoETy7YINqwaUnlosVgKRixN3npBsJzPBcZllpFbiEn/vDJEMu7/NE3xTXJQjzBTn51fdvp906jB9dYTu1ATjH/TLBpxAskZO/1pnBWZpAKVwaVC4ffmV6CUu0t+xBwKHwICjUns8QKJ0nCmC0DMnm4J83oGCnSqNdWiAjKpmBKMu9B/psaL9vT551RB5OOaxeRAMf1Qs/oy0M3UOo4lUvZ
```

However, I am running into a difficulty with this particular json string (it doesn't happen with all). There are extra zeros (reading the HEX) in the server encrypted data before Base64 encoding, which are not there after decoding with Base64 on Arduino (result is the string with the Base64 encoded data):

```
  char encoded[result.length()];
  result.toCharArray(encoded, result.length());

  // Convert back.
  int decodedLength = Base64.decodedLength(encoded, sizeof(encoded));
  char decodedChar[decodedLength];
  Base64.decode(decodedChar, encoded, sizeof(encoded));
  Serial.print("Decoded: "); des.printArray((byte*) decodedChar, decodedLength);
  for (int i = 0; i < decodedLength; i += 8) {
    byte intermitInput[8];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      intermitInput[j] = (byte) decodedChar[i + j];
    }
    Serial.print(i);Serial.print(" ");
    des.decrypt((byte*)decodedChar + i, intermitInput, (byte*)key); // Re-use the decodedChar array as it is already initiated (saving money)
  }
  Serial.println("Finished decription.");
  decodedChar[decodedLength] = '\0';
  Serial.print("Decripted: "); des.printArray((byte*) decodedChar, (int) sizeof(decodedChar));
  Serial.print("Decripted result:\t");
  Serial.println(decodedChar);
```

This results in:

```
Base64 decoded: 1e64fd8c74b2eda44f2ed820dab06949e5a2c5602918b13779e96c2733c1719965a456e2127fef0c910cbbbfcd137c535c9423cc14e7e757ddbe9f74ea37d7584eed404e31ff4cb069c4b2464eff5a670566690a57695b87df995e8252ed2dfb1070287c8a3527b3c4a2749c2982d33279b827cde81829d2a8d756888caa6604a32ef41fe9b1a2fdbd3e79d517938e6b17910c7f542cfe8cb433750ea38954bbf
DES decrypted: 7b22726573756c74223a2253554343455353222c226d657373616765223a22286e6f6e6529222c2022616374696f6e73223a5b7b22616374696f6e223a2263616d70416c61726d222c2276616c7565223a2266616c7365227d2c7b22616374696f6e223a227761726e696e6742656570222c2276616c7565223a2266616c7365227d2c7b22616374696f6e223a226770696f5f3231222c2276616c7565223a30d8e9d029b7c75ed1
json:   {"result":"SUCCESS","message":"(none)", "actions":[{"action":"campAlarm","value":"false"},{"action":"warningBeep","value":"false"},{"action":"gpio_21","value":0⸮⸮⸮)⸮⸮^⸮
```

I guess it is because of the 'missing' '0' (in the HEX) after the Base64 decoding that the last 8 characters if the json are off. This is only a guess, as I don't know the reason those '0' HEX 'characters' are missing. (eg 1e64fd8c07 vs 1e64fd8c7)

Is there anybody know how this happens? The interesting thing is that the string is decrypted correctly apart from the last group of 8 bytes. The string is 163 characters, so is padded upon encoding.

Comment: The result of the decoded json looks a lot of "off-by-one" error that you might be miscount the length of the data or over-count during an iteration, or your buffer is insufficient for the decoded string.... This is just my hunch.

Comment: The base64  string is not the same length on the server and on the arduino.  On the server, the base64 string is shorter than the encrypted string.  base64 strings should be longer than the data they represent.

Comment: The base64 encoded string is the same length, but the result of the decoding is not, but I don't understand how that is. I will check the length of the buffers, and maybe it is a problem with the Base64 library I use, maybe I should look at an alternative.